# How can I isolate pods in namespace using NetworkPolicy without disabling external traffic to Kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-networkpolicy, kubernetes-networking

I am trying to isolate my pods in namespace from other namespaces. I have tried to create a NetworkPolicy:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-from-other-namespaces
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}
```

This NetworkPolicy successfully isolating pods in my namespace from another namespace. But this policy, once applied, disables all external traffic to these pods. Is there any method for only block traffic from other namespaces and allow all external traffic to the pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a kubernetes networkPolicy I don't believe its possible to deny communication between pods while allowing all external traffic.  This is because the kubernetes networkPolicy resource doesn't have a concept of explicit Deny rules.  I would either adjust your approach or consider another network policy that has Deny rules (such as [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/resources/networkpolicy)).

**Solution:**

```
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-other-namespaces
  namespace: prod
spec:
  selector: all()
  types:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - action: Deny
    protocol: TCP
    source:
      namespaceSelector: name == 'dev'
  - action: Allow
  egress:
  - action: Allow
```

Comment: @odenSon, I have tried calico network Policy ,but sadly it didn't work for me .

Comment: @Pratheesh can you share the calico NetworkPolicy resource yaml you used?

Comment: apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-ns
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector: all()
  ingress:
  - action: Allow
    protocol: TCP
    source:
      selector: all()
  - action: Allow
    source:
       nets:
          - 0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 1):

The NetworkPolicy you applied is blocking the traffic from every source.

You can add authorized CIDR blocks in your definition:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: example-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 172.17.0.0/16
```

Comment: Yes i have tried to add a cidr to my policy .But this would allow traffics from that particular cidr and if we give cidr like 0.0.0.0/0 ,all traffics get routed to the pods including traffic from another namespace ..

Comment: 0.0.0.0/0 allows traffic from every source, use the CIDR block of your Loadbalancer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure that you namespace the `NetworkPolicy` resource and restrict the ingress/egress to just namespace.

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: onlywithinnamespace
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          role: mynamespace
    - podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          role: mynamespace
    - podSelector: {}
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

Make sure that your namespace has the right labels to match:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  labels:
    role: mynamespace
  name: mynamespace
```

Comment: ,This would allow traffic from that particular namespace right ? . That is correct as per my first condition . But I am also trying to allow all external traffic .This method is blocking  all external traffics

Comment: External traffic from where?

Comment: External traffic via NodePort . Like if try to expose one of my service using a NodePort ,and try to access the service through nodeport it wont pass that traffic to my service

Comment: If that external traffic is coming from a load balancer you can allow ingress on the load balancer's cidr range on the same policy.

Answer (score 1):

You can allow all traffic but block the ones from internal network.

The Network Policy below allow access to all, exept internal networks (192.168.0.0/16 and 172.23.40.0/24)

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
   name: allow-external
   namespace: dmz
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  - Ingress
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
        - 192.168.0.0/16
        - 172.23.42.0/24
    - namespaceSelector:
         matchLabels:
           name: dmz
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have the same problem and the response in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/56860217/7324872 is great

Please create 2 network policy:

**deny-from-other-namespaces**

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: deny-from-other-namespaces
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector: {}
```

And **web-allow-external**

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: web-allow-external
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: <label>
  ingress:
  - {}
```

The Network policy are not excluding.